# java charset decode issue in converting string to hex code

Tags: java, unicode, byte

I read a string of bytes and I want to convert it to hex code. I know the general data is :

`aa 01 00 1c 1e 38 5a 19 26 fc 00 7a e1 48 00 00 ff bf 00 58 01 2c 00 00 00 64 25 ff`

I convert the string to hex using the following code:

```
 byte[] temp = record.value().getBytes();
                    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
                    for (byte b : temp) {
                        result.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
                        result.append(" "); // delimiter
                    }
                    System.out.println(result);
```

and the output is :

`EF  BF  BD  01  00  1C  1E  39  5A  18  40  EF  BF  BD  00  38  51  EF  BF  BD  00  00  EF  BF  BD  EF  BF  BD  00  48  00  EF  BF  BD  00  00  00  64  EF  BF  BD  1F`

The issue is it changed `aa` byte with `EF  BF  BD`.

So I tried applying Unicodes like the following:

```
byte[] temp = record.value().getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

or

```
byte[] temp = record.value().getBytes("windows-1252");
```

and the output changes to:

`3F  01  00  1C  1E  39  5A  18  40  3F  00  38  51  3F  00  00  3F  3F  00  48  00  3F  00  00  00  64  3F  1F`

this time it changed `aa` to `3F`.

How can I fix this issue and print data correctly?

**Note**: having the same problem in C++, changing data from `char[]` to `unsigned char[]` solved the problem.

Comment: *I know the general data is*: how do you know that? What is the original string? How do you know that it's hex representation is the one you think it is, and which charset is used to transform the characters in that string into those bytes?

Comment: I created this messages(data) using c++ and send them to a UDP port.Now java is listening to that port and read data.

Comment: You didn't answer any of the questions I asked.

Comment: I create this message so I know what the message contains.

Comment: And why don't you tell us, then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "string of bytes"
It is either an array (or list) of bytes, or a String.
In Java String means UTF-16. Bytes don't have an encoding.

EF BF BD is UTF-8 for FFFD, which is the the Unicode replacement character (used for data corruption, when characters cannot be converted to a certain code page).

Since you use record.value().getBytes() I assume that record.value() is a String.
How do you read that string? Where does it come from?
That's a real string, not bytes.
aa 01 00 1c 1e 38 ... does not look like valid bytes in a String (at least not in a string that contains readable text).

The best thing you can do is make sure you get directly bytes, not string and convert. That means that somewhere earlier some bytes got converted to string. And that (potentially) damaged them already.

Comment: You're right. The general data are in byte[] (serialized). I read and deserialized them in string format. So I change serializer to byte[] and it solved.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works fine:

```
public class T14ReadBytes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] temp = new byte[10];
        temp[0] = (byte) 0xaa;
        temp[1] = (byte) 0x01;
        temp[2] = (byte) 0x00;
        temp[3] = (byte) 0x1c;
        temp[4] = (byte) 0x1e;
        temp[5] = (byte) 0x38;
        temp[6] = (byte) 0x5a;
        temp[7] = (byte) 0x19;
        temp[8] = (byte) 0x26;
        temp[9] = (byte) 0xfc;

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : temp) {
            result.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

The result is: 
AA 01 00 1C 1E 38 5A 19 26 FC